# Is it correct to say "The bus driver carried me to school in his bus"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

In the dictionary, they say

> A vehicle + carry + people

For example, "*the bus can carry 100 passengers.*"

My question is,

**can we say?**:

> A driver + carry + people + in + a vehicle

For example,

Is it correct to say "*The bus driver carried me to school in his bus*"?

But, it seems native speakers say "*The bus driver took/brought me to school in his bus*" but I am not so sure.

Comment: It is the *bus* that carries people: the driver *drives* them. To avoid repetition with 'driver' and 'drove' you can say "the bus driver *took* me to school in his bus."

Comment: Just say *The bus driver drove me to school." You don't need to add "in his bus" because of course the bus driver used the bus to drive you! You'd only mention the vehicle if it wasn't a bus. The only time you can get away with saying "The bus driver carried me to school" was if you lived in the SE US.

Comment: It is not natural to talk of the bus driver carrying a passenger in any variety of English that I am familiar with, but it would not surprise me at all to find that it was normal in _some_ English dialect.

Comment: SE US, particularly. N GA uses the phrase "carry" to mean "transport/drive", as in "Can I carry you home?"